# My postfix server is rejecting my client: 4.7.25 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [96.9.90.28]

Tags: postfix

My postfix host is rejecting my client with this message:

```
4.7.25 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [96.9.90.28].
```

From the cli on the postfix server, I get this:

```
root@civicrm:~# host 96.9.90.28
28.90.9.96.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer 28.90.9.96.sinet.com.kh.
```

So, there is a pointer record. Why would it be rejected.

I then put in a phony hostname in /etc/hosts with the same IP address and the was accepted and email successfully sent.

I then added `96.9.90.28 28.90.9.96.sinet.com.kh` to the /etc/hosts file and it was also accepted.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Your email client should be configured to send mail on port 587, not port 25.

Answer (score 2):

You postfix configuration has [reject_unknown_client_hostname](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unknown_client_hostname) which rejects mails because 28.90.9.96.sinet.com.kh. doesn't resolve back to 96.9.90.28.

Comment: What is the process used by this directive to determine that 28.90.9.sinet.kh doesn't resolve back to 96.9.90.28? I thought it just looked for a PTR record

Comment: I have a feeling this was a temporary thing (internet in Cambodia can be flaky). I put the directive back in and took the entry in /etc/hosts out and mail is going out without fail.

Comment: @Vietyank , my answer contains a link to the postfix documentation which describes what this check does.

Comment: Yes. I see that.

What is the process that causes the name mapping to fail?

Comment: @Vietyank the process is the domain name resolution, when DNS server fails to return expected answer then this process fails. In your case DNS servers were returning NXDOMAIN for 28.90.9.96.sinet.com.kh.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation. I had this problematic configuration:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions =
        reject_unknown_client_hostname
```

Some years ago I added that rule and was effective to block some spam, but now it was also blocking myself when I was in "strange" locations, even if I was logged-in, with that error (`4.7.25 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname`) and that was frustrating.

Some people suggest to just disable `reject_unknown_client_hostname`. I don't like this solution. I think you can do better and just allow logged-in people.

So here my solution:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated
        reject_unknown_client_hostname
```

Now I'm not blocked anymore, since I'm already logged-in. I hope this tip can be useful for you.